# On sparse $0/1$ linear equations solvable with compressed sensing

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, finite-fields, coding-theory, compressed-sensing

If you have a system of $m$ linearly independent equations in $n$ variables with domain $0/1$ and we know there is at least one solution with at most $d$ variables to be $1$ then if $m$ at least a certain bound then can we guarantee that we can get this solution in $poly(mn)$ time with compressed sensing methods?

If so then what bound should $m$ satisfy for both $\Bbb F_2$ and $\Bbb Z$ cases and also do we need some condition on the independent equations? Typically what tools are used in such situations?